# how to set tab index to xaml tree view items?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, treeview, tabindex

I have a tree view in which I am dynamically setting checkboxes as treeview items using the c# code.
Now I want to iterate through all the treeview items when I press the tab button.
Currently, my tree view item is getting focused when I press the tab button, but to indexing any of my tree view items.
 xaml code

```
<TreeView x:Name="resultTree" Grid.Column="2" Height="280" 
Margin="0,60,89,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="345" Grid.RowSpan="2" TabIndex="3" />
```

C# code:

```
TreeViewItem accountTree = new TreeViewItem();
accountTree.Focus();
accountTree.IsExpanded = true;
j = 4;
CheckBox currentAccountChBx = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
currentAccountChBx.Content = "A";
currentAccountChBx.Name = "accountChBx" + i;
currentAccountChBx.TabIndex = j;
currentAccountChBx.Focusable = true;
currentAccountChBx.IsTabStop = false;
j++;
```

[image: Tab Index flow should be like this]
Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: The way treeview works by default is you use arrow keys to move up and down.( Like any itemscontrol). This is probably because the children of a treeviewitem are actually part of that treeviewitem because it's a headereditemscontrol. By default the container or treeviewitem itself will usually be able to take focus so you might need to set properties on that to avoid two arrow presses.

Comment: Building treeview items with code is the winforms way of doing things. For wpf templating data into UI using hierarchicaldatatemplates is the way pretty much everyone does this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursion: for each node, iterate through its children. For example, show each node content in message box:

```
void ExecuteOnEachNode(TreeView tree, Action<TreeViewItem> func) // Executes 'func' on each item with it as parameter
{
    foreach (TreeViewItem item in tree.Items)
    {
        func(item);

        foreach (TreeViewItem subitem in item.Items)
        {
            ExecuteOnEachNode(item, func); // Trasvel over current item children
        }
    }
}

ExecuteOnEachNode(item => MessageBox.Show(item.Header.ToString()));
```

Then, you should set the tab indx for everyone. For example,

```
int counter = 2;
ExecuteOnEachNode(item => item.TabIndex = counter++);
```

Comment: setting tab index to all tree view items in not triggering tab iteration over tree view items like check box, I set tab index to checkbox even but not worknig